# Autogenerate Jquery Autocomplete in CRUD grails scaffolding (one-to-many relationships)

Tags: grails, jquery-autocomplete, grails-plugin, scaffolding

I have altered the src/templates/scaffolding/renderEditor.template  file in a grails project, in order to insert, the necessary html field boxes (and javascript code) to configure and use jquery autocomplete, in all the relationships "many-to-one". (The code is shown below)

The autogenerated autocomplete (_form.gsp) works correctly ... but I need to show the correct values (code and description) into the autocomplete textbox when a user edit a record using the scaffolding.

To do that, I need to identify two fields inside the domain: one for code and the other for the description.

To face this problem, I have tried to create two dummies constraints, using the plugin "constraints", the first one used like code, the second one used like a description. I don't like  this solution, because the contrainsts could be used several times into the domain.

The code altered into the src/templates/scaffolding/renderEditor.template file is the following: (Note the two input boxes and Javascript code used for autocomplete):

```
private renderManyToOne(domainClass, property) {
    if (property.association) {


        /*  ORIGINAL CODE inside comments
            def sb = new StringBuilder()
        sb << '<g:select'
            // id is "x" and name is "x.id" as the label will have for="x" and "." in an id will confuse CSS
            sb << ' id="' << property.name << '"'
            sb << ' name="' << property.name << '.id"'
            sb << ' from="${' << property.type.name << '.list()}"'
            sb << ' optionKey="id"'
            if (isRequired()) sb << ' required=""'
            sb << ' value="${' << "${domainInstance}?.${property.name}" << '?.id}"'
            sb << ' class="many-to-one"'
            sb << renderNoSelection(property)
            sb << '/>'
            sb as String

            */


        def sb = new StringBuilder()

        // hidden field for domain.id

        sb << '<input type=\"hidden\" '
        sb << ' id="' << property.name << '.id"'
        sb << ' name="' << property.name  << '.id"'
        sb << ' value="${' << "${domainInstance}" << '?.id}" '
        sb << '/>\n'

        // Text field to show the description generated by autocomplete
        sb << '\t<input type=\"text\" '
        sb << ' id="' << property.name << '"'
        sb << ' name="' << property.name  << '"'
        if (isRequired()) sb << ' required="" '
        sb << 'style=\"width: 600px;\" '
        sb << ' value="${' << "${domainInstance}?.${property.name}" << '?.id}"'
        // sb << '${' << "${property.name}" << '"'
        sb << '/>'

        def js = new StringBuilder()
        js << '''
        <script type="text/javascript">

            /*
             * Remember include jquery and jquery-ui libraries into head section of edit.gsp file
             *   < g:javascript library="jquery"/>
             *   < g:javascript library="jquery-ui"/>
             */

            \$(document).ready(function() {
        '''
           js << '\t\$("#' << property.name << '").focus(function(){this.select(); });\n'

           js << '\t\t$("#' << property.name << '").autocomplete({\n'

           js << '''
                      source: function(request, response){
                          \$.ajax({
                              // Define Remote datasource into the controller
           '''
           js << '            \t\t url: "'
           js << '/' << grails.util.Metadata.current.'app.name' << '/' << property.name << '/' << 'autoCompleteList",'

           js << '''
                              data: request,
                              success: function(data){
                                  // Get the response (JSON format)
                                  response(data);
                              },
                              error: function(){
                                  // Handle server errors
                                  response("Error after search records. Try Again.")
                              }
                          });
                      },
                      // General options: Triggered only after minimum 2 characters have been entered and others
                      minLength: 2,
                      delay: 1,
                      autoFocus: true,
                      // Event handler when user selects a Loinc from the list.
                      select: function(event, ui) {
                          // update the hidden field.
           '''
           js <<  '\t\t\t\t  \$("#' << property.name << '\\.id").val(ui.item.id);'
           js << '''
                      }
                });
           });
        </script>
        '''
        sb << js
        sb as String


    }
```

The domain using the dummy contraints  (autoid and autodesc):

```
class LOINC {

    static searchable = {
        only = ["code", "shortName", "longName", "property", "system", "scale", "method", "time"]
    }

    String code         // LOINC_NUM         * 0
    String shortName    // SHORTNAME         * 29
    String longName     // LONG_COMMON_NAME  * 35
    String name         // BASE_NAME         * 21
    String component    // COMPONENT         * 1
    String property     // PROPERTY          * 2
    String time         // TIME_ASPCT        * 3
    String system       // SYSTEM            * 4
    String scale        // SCALE_TYP         * 5
    String method       // METHOD_TYP        * 6

    static constraints = {
        code(nullable: false, unique: true, blank: false, maxSize: 100, autoid: true)
        shortName(nullable: false)
        longName(nullable: false, autodesc: true)
        name(nullable: false, maxSize: 100)
        component(nullable: false)
        property(nullable: false)
        time(nullable: false)
        system(nullable: false)
        scale(nullable: false)
        method(nullable: false)
    }

    String toString(){
        "${code} ${longName}"
    }
}
```

The code inside the controler:

```
 def autoCompleteList = {
        def loincAutoCompleteService = new LOINCAutoCompleteService()
        render loincAutoCompleteService.loincList(params) as JSON
 }
```

The service:

```
class LOINCAutoCompleteService {

    def loincList(params) {

        // Creates a new query Object
        def query = {
            or {
                like("code", "${params.term}%") // term is the parameter send by jQuery autocomplete
                like("longName", "${params.term}%")
                like("shortName", "${params.term}%")
            }
            projections { // good to select only the required columns.
                property("id")
                property("code")
                property("longName")
            }
        }

        def loincSelectList = [] // aArray List to add each Loinc details
        def clist = LOINC.createCriteria().list(query)


        clist.each {
            // Add to map. jQuery autocomplete expects the JSON object to be with id/label/value
            def loincMap = [:]

            loincMap.put("id", it[0])

            // Label is text showed int he drop-down list
            loincMap.put("label", it[1] + " : " + it[2])

            // Values is the code to be returned when the user select an item from drop-down list
            loincMap.put("value", it[1] + " : " + it[2])

            // Add the row to the array list
            loincSelectList.add(loincMap)
        }


        return loincSelectList

    }
}
```

I want something like that inside the domain class:

```
<code>
static autocompleteAble = {
        fields = ["code", "longName"]
}
</code>
```

Then access this array from the src/templates/scaffolding/renderEditor.template  in order to get the field names (code and longName) and generate the correct html code in _forms.gsp and fix the problem.

Other solution? Any Ideas?

Many Thanks in Advance. ... and excuse my bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading and testing and testing again ... I have found the answer, follow the steps:

1. Add the following code to the Domain class:

   class DomainClass {
       String codeField;
       String descriptionField;
       static autoCompleteConfig = ["codeField", "descriptionField"]
   }
2. Change the src/templates/scaffolding/renderEditor.template (only the renderManyToOne method):

   private renderManyToOne(domainClass, property) {

   ```
       def AUTOCOMPLETE_PROPERTY = "autoCompleteConfig"
       def className = property.type.name

       def autoCompleteProperty = org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.GrailsClassUtils.getStaticPropertyValue(property.referencedDomainClass.clazz, AUTOCOMPLETE_PROPERTY)
       def sb = new StringBuilder()
       // sb << "\n<!-- getFullName(): " <<   domainClass.getFullName() << " property.type.name: " << property.type.name << " property.referencedDomainClass.propertyName: " << property.referencedDomainClass.propertyName <<  "     property.referencedDomainClass: " << property.referencedDomainClass <<  " -->\n"
       if (autoCompleteProperty != null) {

           if (autoCompleteProperty[0] ) {
               if (property.association) {

                   // hidden field for domain.id

                   sb << '<input type=\"hidden\" '
                   sb << ' id=  "' << property.name << '.id"'
                   sb << ' name="' << property.name << '.id"'
                   sb << ' value="${' << "${domainInstance}" << '?.id}" '
                   sb << '/>\n'

                   // Text field to show the description generated by autocomplete
                   sb << '\t<input type=\"text\" '
                   sb << ' id=  "' << property.name  << '_' << (autoCompleteProperty[1]? autoCompleteProperty[1]:'Description')  << '\" '
                   sb << ' name="' << property.name  << '_' << (autoCompleteProperty[1]? autoCompleteProperty[1]:'Description')  << '\" '
                   if (isRequired()) sb << ' required="" '
                   sb << 'style=\"width: 600px;\" '

                   sb << ' value="${'
                   sb << "${domainInstance}?.${property.name}" << '?.' << autoCompleteProperty[0] << '}' << (autoCompleteProperty[1]? '' : '"' )

                   if (autoCompleteProperty[1]) {
                       sb << ': ${' << "${domainInstance}?.${property.name}" << '?.' << autoCompleteProperty[1] << (autoCompleteProperty[2]? '}' : '}"' )
                   }

                   if (autoCompleteProperty[2]) {
                       sb << ': ${' << "${domainInstance}?.${property.name}" << '?.' << autoCompleteProperty[2] << '}"'
                   }


                   sb << ' />'

                   def js = new StringBuilder()
                   js << '''
                   <script type="text/javascript">

                       /*
                        * Remember include jquery and jquery-ui libraries into head section of edit.gsp file
                        *   < g:javascript library="jquery"/>
                        *   < g:javascript library="jquery-ui"/>
                        *
                        */

                       \$(document).ready(function() {
                   '''
                      js << '\t\$("#' << property.name << '").focus(function(){this.select(); });\n'

                      js << '\t\t\t\t\t\t' // Tabs to sort the output
                      js << '\$("#' << property.name  << '_' << (autoCompleteProperty[1]? autoCompleteProperty[1]:'Description')  << '").autocomplete({\n'

                      js << '''
                                 source: function(request, response){
                                     \$.ajax({
                                         // Define Remote datasource into the controller
                      '''
                      js << '            \t\t url: "'
                      js << '/' << grails.util.Metadata.current.'app.name' << '/' << property.name << '/' << 'autoCompleteList",'

                      js << '''
                                         data: request,
                                         success: function(data){
                                             // Get the response (JSON format)
                                             response(data);
                                         },
                                         error: function(){
                                             // Handle server errors
                                             response("Error after search records. Try Again.")
                                         }
                                     });
                                 },
                                 // General options: Triggered only after minimum 2 characters have been entered and others
                                 minLength: 2,
                                 delay: 1,
                                 autoFocus: true,
                                 // Event handler when user choose un item from the list.
                                 select: function(event, ui) {
                                     // update the hidden field.
                      '''
                      js <<  '\t\t\t\t  '
                      js << '\$("#' << property.name << '\\\\.id").val(ui.item.id);'

                      js << '''

                                 }
                           });
                      });
                   </script>
                   '''
                   sb << js
                   sb as String


               }
           }
       } else {


           sb << '<g:select'
           // id is "x" and name is "x.id" as the label will have for="x" and "." in an id will confuse CSS
           sb << ' id="' << property.name << '"'
           sb << ' name="' << property.name << '.id"'
           sb << ' from="${' << property.type.name << '.list()}"'
           sb << ' optionKey="id"'
           if (isRequired()) sb << ' required=""'
           sb << ' value="${' << "${domainInstance}?.${property.name}" << '?.id}"'
           sb << ' class="many-to-one"'
           sb << renderNoSelection(property)
           sb << '/>'
           sb as String


       }

   }
   ```
3. Add the jquery libraries to src/templates/scaffolding/edit.gsp. Remember to install the jquery plugin:
4. Write your own autoCompleteRoutine inside the Domain controller, something like:

   def autoCompleteList = {
           def domainAutoCompleteService = new DomainAutoCompleteService()
           render domainAutoCompleteService.domainList(params) as JSON
   }
5. Write your own domainAutoCompleteService, something like:

   package packageName

   ```
   // Change the words "Domain" and "domain" with your own Domain class name
   class DomainAutoCompleteService {

       def domainList(params) {

           // Creates a new query Object
           def query = {
               or {
                   // term is the parameter send by jQuery autocomplete
                   like("codeField", "${params.term}%") 
                   like("descriptionField", "${params.term}%")
                   like("otherField", "${params.term}%")
               }
               projections { // good to select only the required columns.
                   property("id")
                   property("codeField")
                   property("descriptionField")
               }
           }

           def domainSelectList = [] 
           // Replace the word "Domain" by your own domain Name
           def clist = Domain.createCriteria().list(query)


           clist.each {
               // Add to map. jQuery autocomplete expects the JSON object to be with id/label/value
               def map = [:]

               map.put("id", it[0])

               // Label is text showed int he drop-down list
               map.put("label", it[1] + " : " + it[2])

               // Values is the code to be returned when the user select an item from drop-down list
               map.put("value", it[1] + " : " + it[2])

               // Add the row to the array list
               domainSelectList.add(map)
           }


           return domainSelectList

       }
   }
   ```
6. Generate the views .... and voila! All is working.

Any Comments? I think can be more elegant but is the first step ...

Comment: Jaime - I think this is a pretty cool solution.  If you ever had time and could figure out how to wrap it all together it would make a good plugin.